# Xcode - When to use a UIView or a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If I want to list some items from a database, do I need to add a `UIView` and a `UITableView` to my ViewController? or just add the `UITableView` to my `ViewController`?

Comment: why the downvotes people? Be nice to new users... upvoting to compensate for all the downvotes...

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I am not really sure why I would get a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You must already be having a `UIView` as part of your `ViewController`, Just add `UITableView` as a subview to your `UIView`.

The `UIView` of a `ViewController` can be accessed as `[self.view];`. So what you need to do is `[self.view addSubview:yourTableView];`. Using `setFrame` properly sets it in the x,y,width,height that you need.

Comment: Ok I understand. Should I also create my own UIView subclass and hook that into the UIView? If so, what is the advantage?

Comment: yes you could do that. Dont think of it as an advantage, it more of convenience. If you need a container where you want to have say 1 UIImageView, 1 UILabel. You could create a UIView and put these elements in that view. so really it depends on your needs.

Comment: I was watching the Standford video series on ItunesU and Hegarty says to always create a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `UITableView` cause you are already have a `UIView`, Please check this [tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) on how to use `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

its just depend on your project layout if you want to add tableview then you can use predefined function like didselectrow,moverow,editingrow,willdisplay etc...it totally depend on your need and layout specification and last thing tableview is better than using view instead on another view.